# Travis-Ci.org give me an error message

Tags: php, oop, travis-ci

I have a problem, I'm using Travis-ci.org but, it always tell me that my build fail, and I don't know why.
Here is my GitHub project : https://github.com/white-frameworks/White-PHP

Comment: Please post the code in your question directly, instead of providing a link to an external site.  Thank you.

Comment: I understand why you are asking this, but in my case, it's a big project, so I can't paste all my code. @JustinTime

Comment: Ah, okay.  Hope someone can get it working, I'd take a look if I had any experience with Travis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added `phpunit`'s XML or anything. There are no test cases. This is the [output in your Travis Job](https://travis-ci.org/white-frameworks/White-PHP/jobs/169825991):

```
The command "phpunit" exited with 2.
```

You have to add the `Test.php` like this, but in your [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/white-frameworks/White-PHP/blob/master/.travis.yml), there's nothing:

```
language: php
php:
- 5.5
- 5.4
- hhvm
script: phpunit Test.php
```

You need to add the PHPUnit's configuration. Read more on how to integrate PHPUnit by looking at [**Building a PHP project**](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php).

Comment: Doesn't work, see the log https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/169832146/log.txt?deansi=true

Comment: @ArthurGuiot Fix the error mate! `Warning: require_once(./white/functions.php): failed to open stream `

Comment: I fixed it, but it still failing, I think your answer is right, but it doesn't work for me @praveenkumar

Comment: Doesn't work, same error, maybe the path should be given in a different way

Comment: @VivekChaturvedi Can you post a new question with all your configuration details?